# ¿Como ejecutar una función luego de que cargó completamente Elfinder js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Estoy trabajando con Elfinder js y quiero iniciar un tour cuando termine de cargar, para ello estoy utilizando Bootstrap Tour, el problema es que no encuentro la forma de ejecutar el tour cuando termina la carga de Elfinder, siguiendo la documentación oficial (https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Client-event-API), estoy realizando esto pero no funciona:

```
            handlers : {
                load : function(event, elfinderInstance) {
                    // define tour
                    var tour = new Tour({    
                        steps: [{
                            element: "#nav-l1_Lw",
                            title: "Title of my step",
                            content: "Content of my step"
                        }, {
                        element: "#2",
                            title: "Title of my step",
                            content: "Content of my step"
                        }]
                    });

                    // init tour
                    tour.init();

                    // start tour
                    tour.start();  
                }
            }
```

¿Alguien me puede orientar un poco?. Gracias!